# Do English speakers never say "snow won't fall"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I'm familiar with "it won't snow".
But do English speakers never say "snow won't fall"?

Comment: "Snow will not fall unless the meteorological conditions are exactly right."

Comment: @KateBunting Is any English speaker use "snow won't fall" instead of "it won't snow"?

Comment: **Does** any English speaker use it? See [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snow+won%27t+fall&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: @KateBunting Does "snow will not fall" and "it won't snow mean the same"?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the examples found by my Ngram search? They include sentences like "Snow won't fall tonight".

Comment: @KateBunting I'm really desperate. In my language, 눈이 안 내릴것이다 is directly translated into snow won't fall but English is it won't snow. I'm very confused.

Comment: It's not that we'd *never* say it... the context would have to be correct. There are two levels of what is "idiomatic" - if something is grammatically correct, clear from confusion, and sounds natural then it is idiomatic, then there are phrases so often repeated that they develop a specific meaning of their own and are 'idioms'. This is certainly the former.

Comment: You asked "Do English speakers never say "Snow won't fall"? I demonstrated to you that we sometimes do, although "It won't snow" is undoubtedly the _usual_ way to say it. If you had included the reason for your confusion in your question, I could have explained it better.

Comment: @KateBunting Sorry, my English is bad, so I can't control myself as I wish.

Comment: @Collins You may find people's expectations of you are higher than they might be because you appear with an English name. If they know you are Chinese (or is it Korean) and trying to make the huge adjustment to English - you may attract more sympathy. Why don't you use your given name?

Comment: @WS2 Actually, it's not my name. It's just "collins" in "collins' dictionary". But thank you I think I should change my name into a younger and cuter name.

Comment: @Collins, merely identifying yourself at the start of a post as a native Korean speaker would earn you the leeway that WS2 is taking about.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum the fact the OP asks "But do English speakers never say "snow won't fall"?" already tells us the OP is not a native speaker. If they were American, British, Australian  etc the question would probably be something like "Why don't we say "snow won't fall” in English?”

Comment: @Mari-LouA, my only intention was to clarify WS2’s purpose and offer another way that OP might achieve it. I didn't mean that one should always, or even often, lead with one’s nationality, but only to illustrate that one could.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I was trying to make a helpful observation. There are other ways of knowing if someone called Ethelred or Alfred is a non-native speaker :)

Comment: @Collins - You don't have to use your real name on stack exchange sites, but more generally when speaking to English speakers, it's not really a good idea to give yourself a different name or a "cute name" in English. We really don't expect foreigners to adopt English names. This seems to be a common thing for English learners in China/Korea. You could just transliterate the characters into the Roman alphabet.  I think most people would probably like to know your real name.

Comment: I just found this question for the first time and thought it should be closed for not being clear enough. But your comment about Korean translation helps clarify. Please use the "edit" button to add it to the question, since comments aren't a permanent part of questions.

Comment: @BillyKerr There may be good reasons why someone doesn't use their real name - I see no compulsion for them to do so. But for anyone whose native language is not Indo-European - especially Chinese or Korean - they are working with something quite foreign to them, and it might be helpful if they began by saying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn this around, do Korean people never say "It won't snow"?  Why not?

In Korean (as I understand it) there is no verb "to snow". So in Korean you need to use a verb like "fall" or "come".

English is not Korean.  In English there is a verb "to snow" and a noun "snow".  It is grammatically correct to say "Snow won't fall". And it is grammatically correct to say "It won't snow".  However only the second is idiomatic.

You would use "Snow won't fall" if you want to particularly focus on the "falling" aspect.  "Snow won't fall in Edinburgh tonight but there will be deep drifts from yesterday".  Even then the "It won't snow" form would mean the same.

There's nothing confusing, if you remember that English isn't the same as word-by-word translated Korean. Sometimes we have a verb that you don't have. Sometimes we don't have a verb that you do have, and in those cases word by word translation will be bad or wrong.

Comment: As for what is idiomatic?  What is idiomatic in Korean?  "눈이낙하하다" or "눈이떨어진다" or  눈이 오다 .  Why? There is no logic to what is idiomatic.

Comment: 눈 오다 is the most used expression. Because "이“ which is a subject-indicator can be omitted". 비 (rain) 오다.

Answer (score 1):

**Snow won't fall** would be very strange. No native speaker of English who is engaged in an informal conversation with another native speaker would choose that way to say "We are not going to get snow today" unless there are some special and highly unusual circumstances to justify it.

Answer (score 1):

- "It **won't snow** today" OK
- "It's **not going to snow** today" OK

By definition snow is frozen water that *falls from* the sky. When it snows (verb), it implies that the snow (noun) is falling down.

- "Snow **won't fall** today“ much less common but understandable.